# angular matAutocomplete box is below bootstrap navbar component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I am trying to use angular material matAutocomplete mat-options in bootstrap Navbar, here is my code

```
    <li class="nav-item">
      <form class="example-form">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
              {{option}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
    </li>
```

[image: snapshot]

You can see in snapshot first item of mat-options is under navbar.
autocomplete example is working fine but suggestion box is appearing under the bootstrap how can I make mat-option on top of the navbar.

adding class .mat-option and z-index css property has no effect.

```
.mat-option{
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It needs to be in a different li tag

Answer (score 2):

you can do that in two ways. the only thing that you need to remember is if your navbar is having z-index more than 1000 it will overlap the matAutoComplete dropdown.

1. add this to your CSS file (preferred)

   ```
   .navbar{
   ```

   z-index: 1000 ;
     }
2. or this to your CSS file

   .cdk-overlay-container{z-index: 10001 ;}

Comment: While this does work, it's not a good solution if you have other things that use the overlay. Like modals, because your toolbar will also overlap the overlay for the modal, still allowing you to interact with your toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add CSS **z-index** in your component css section as below

```
.mat-autocomplete-panel{
  z-index: 99999;    
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. anyway thanks for the reply.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, please remove px from 9999 and try again

Comment: Do not use `ng-deep`, it is deprecated https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: Thanks, Elias to updating me.